# Host screen turns off when I start X server in docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, xserver

I created docker container with X server inside. I use it for some off-screen OpenGL rendering.
This container should work on any system (with or without X server running) and it should use hardware GPU if it exists (so I cannot use xvfb).

When I use this container on server-like system without GUI, everything works perfectly. But when I run the container on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop, the screen turns off each time I start X server in my container.

I start container with --priviliged so /dev folder is shared with container. I believe it involves some kind of conflict.

Is there a way to start X inside the container such as host X server is still working?

**UPDATE:**

I see the following in Xorg.0.log:

```
AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
(II) NOUVEAU(0): NVLeaveVT is called.
```

**UPDATE:**

Can I use xvfb instead of real Xorg server? Does it support actual hardware GPU rendering?

Comment: Sounds like it tries to grab the GPU hardware and is allowed to.  This will not end well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work - you're effectively trying to use two X servers - the host and the container - and I suspect they are both expecting to have exclusive use of the video card.

What you can do instead is use the X server on the host from the container by bind-mounting the X Server socket. This SO answer explains how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334301/4332

I'm not sure this will help in your particular case, but I don't entirely understand why you need an XServer running in the container at all. I think you should still have access to the GPU with --privileged.

Comment: It is not convenient to use host X server, because it may not exist. Ideally, I'd want a solution that works on both desktop and server machines. I need X server because I need "display" in OpenGL context initialization: Display* display = XOpenDisplay( displayName );

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using CPU for OpenGL, you can set up an X server inside the container with the Xdummy video driver with GLX extensions. But of course you won't be able to see a thing because the video driver is, well, dummy.

If you do want to play with GUIs, try TurboVNC + VirtualGL and use the Xdummy server as the 3D X server.